# Cannot get error messages from Symfony Form 4.2

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I am using Symfony Form 4.2 in standalone way. I have a form element with few fields in HTML file. To have validation in PHP as well, I replicated the form in PHP using Symfony Form 4.2 like below:

```
    $formFactory = Forms::createFormFactoryBuilder()
    ->addExtension(new ValidatorExtension($validator))
    ->getFormFactory();

    $form = $formFactory->createBuilder()
    ->add('pk_firstname', TextType::class, [
        'constraints' => [new NotBlank(),
            new Length([
                    'min' => 2,
                    'max' => 50,
                    'minMessage' => 'Your first name must be at least {{ limit }} characters long',
                    'maxMessage' => 'Your first name cannot be longer than {{ limit }} characters']
            )],
    ])
    ->add('pk_lastname', TextType::class, [
        'constraints' => [new NotBlank(),
            new Length([
                    'min' => 2,
                    'max' => 50,
                    'minMessage' => 'Your first name must be at least {{ limit }} characters long',
                    'maxMessage' => 'Your first name cannot be longer than {{ limit }} characters']
            )],
    ])
    ->add('pk_emailaddress', EmailType::class, [
        'constraints' => [new NotBlank(), new Email(
            [
                'message' => 'The email "{{ value }}" is not a valid email.',
                'mode' => 'strict',
            ]
        )],
    ])
    ->add('pk_phonenumber', TelType::class, [
        'constraints' => [],
    ])
    ->add('pk_message', TextareaType::class, [
        'constraints' => [new NotBlank()],
    ])
    ->getForm();
```

When the form is submitted in the frontend, I prevent default behaviour by using JavaScript and make a AJAX request to PHP file with submitted data where Symfony form is used to validate correctness of submitted data.

Then, I manually submit the form like below:

```
    $request = Request::createFromGlobals();

$submitData = array("pk_firstname" => $request->request->get('pk_firstname'),
    "pk_lastname" => $request->request->get('pk_lastname'),
    "pk_emailaddress" => $request->request->get('pk_emailaddress'),
    "pk_phonenumber" => $request->request->get('pk_phonenumber'),
    "pk_message" => $request->request->get('pk_message'));

$form->submit($submitData);
```

The problem here is, upon invalid data are submitted `isValid()` method on `$form` object return **the form is not valid** but `getErrors()` methods return empty array.

Is there something I do wrongly here?

I'd like to get fields which violated the constraints and which constraints so that I can pass those error messages to JavaScript to display in the frontend.

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly, you just want to serialize a form object, right?

Therefor you can do the following:

```
 public function getErrorMessages(FormInterface $form)
    {
        $errors = array();
        foreach ($form->getErrors(true, true) as $error) {
            $propertyPath = str_replace('data.', '', $error->getCause()->getPropertyPath());
            $errors[$propertyPath] = $error->getMessage();
        }

        return $errors;
    }
```

You have to pass your form object to this method e.g. `$serializedErrors = getErrorMessages($form)`.